# White-space: nowrap + overflow:initial doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, word-wrap

I've got this markup in my table.

```
<td class="unbreakable">
  <span class="unbreakable">
    a lot of stupid text
  </span>
</td>
```

The *unbreakable* class is as follows.

```
.unbreakable {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: initial;
}
```

While, indeed, unbreakable, it just makes the table wider (too wide!) instead of cutting off. I've tested to apply the class to each control by itself and both at the same time (not that it should do any good - I'm just annoyed). I noticed that the same misbehavior occurs for *hidden* too, so I'm guessing that it's *overflow* that doesn't bite.

I'm setting the width of the whole *TABLE* and the *TD* element explicitly. To no avail...

What do I miss and how can I kill the problem?

Comment: Without setting any width constraints, the default behavior is to make the table cell only as wide as is necessary to contain the text in one line without wrapping. You haven't really mentioned what problem you're facing...

Comment: I'm setting my whole table to *width:100%*. Do I need to use pixel width? Also, I'm setting the width of the *TD*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you aren't hiding your overflow (initial is defaulting to visible and I don't think [initial is valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)) the table cell will always expand to the size of any non breaking element within it.

You can make it default to 100% by changing it to `overflow:hidden` and adding the following to your table:

```
table {table-layout:fixed;}
```

if you do this you can also make use of `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fNT32/2/)

Comment: `initial` is a special keyword that can be applied to virtually any property, much like `inherit`, except that it means the initial value of the given property. It's valid insofar as it is supported within the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're searching for `overflow: hidden` with `table-layout: fixed`.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLnCS/)

html:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="unbreakable">
          <span class="unbreakable">
             a lot of stupid text a lot of stupid text a lot of stupid text a lot of stupid text a lot of stupid text
          </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.unbreakable {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Notice if you remove the `table-layout:fixed` part, the text won't get wrapped.